# how not to throw an error even for 'None' type?

Tags: python

I am trying to create HTML format (for sending automatic emails)from JSON data I get from an internal database, I am getting the following error for 'None' type,I want to capture 'None' type aswell?how to not throw an error even for 'None' type?

INPUT:-

```
{'total': 0, 'Resolution': None, 'key': u'CNSSDEBUG-151394', 'summary': u'[Lenovo][NFA344A][Win10] - [QCA6174_9377.WIN.1.0-10366-QCARMTFX86WZ-2] - Undetermined crash root cause'}
```

CODE:-

```
........
    for item in jiradb :
        MailBody = MailBody + "<tr>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        print item['key']
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + item['key'].rstrip('\n!') + "</td>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + item['summary'].rstrip('\n!') + "</td>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + item['Resolution'].rstrip('\n!') + "</td>"
        icount = icount + 1
```

.......................

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sns.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "sns.py", line 215, in main
    sendmail(meta,jiradb,total_no_crashes)
  File "sns.py", line 47, in sendmail
    MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + item['Resolution'].rstrip('\n!') + "</td>"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract each field from the dict using `dict.get(key,default)` to avoid missing fields, and then use `or` to cover the `None` case

For example

```
item['Resolution'].rstrip('\n!')
```

becomes

```
(item.get('Resolution', None) or '').rstrip('\n!')
```

Then you probably want a helper function

```
   def get_field(item, field, default=''):
       return (item.get(field, None) or default).rstrip('\n!')
```

Then your loop is a little cleaner and you are safer from typos

```
........
    for item in jiradb :
        MailBody = MailBody + "<tr>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + str(icount) + "</td>"
        print get_field(item, 'key')
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + get_field(item,'key') + "</td>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + get_field(item,'summary') + "</td>"
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + get_field(item,'Resolution') + "</td>"
        icount = icount + 1
```

Comment: nit: `dict.get` returns `None` if the key is missing already, so `d.get('key', None)` is exactly the same as `d.get('key')`

Comment: Yeah, but I just wanted to make the 'default' explicit for readers

Comment: Actually, why not `item.get('Resolution', '').rstrip('\n')`?

Comment: Because this will return `None` in the case of the example input, so `rstrip` will fail.  The default is only used if the key is absent

Comment: Oh, derp :-).  You're right.  `item.get('Resolution', '').rstrip('\n')` doesn't work.

Comment: @kdopen - can you explain the connection between the get in `item.get` and the function name `get_field`,I though get is an inbuild python thing,why do we need a helper function?

Comment: It's just a function name - you could call it `shirley` if you want :)

The idea is simply to wrap the process of fetching a possibly missing, possibly `None` key from `item` and keep the calling code cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

It might sound like too broad of an answer, but I would suggest to switch to a *template engine*, like [`mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/), instead of trying to manually construct HTML using the string concatenation. You would solve this kind of problem just by using the variable placeholders and built-in or custom filters.

As a bonus, you would get a nice separation of logic (your Python code) and presentation - the generated HTML. A much cleaner and more testable code.

---

Here is a working sample using `jinja2` (created a [custom `rstrip` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters)):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

jiradb = [
    {'total': 0, 'Resolution': None, 'key': u'CNSSDEBUG-151394', 'summary': u'[Lenovo][NFA344A][Win10] - [QCA6174_9377.WIN.1.0-10366-QCARMTFX86WZ-2] - Undetermined crash root cause'},
    {'total': 1, 'Resolution': 'fixed', 'key': u'CNSSDEBUG-151395', 'summary': u'Some other summary'},
]

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
env.filters['rstrip'] = lambda value, s: value.rstrip(s) if value else ''

template = env.get_template('index.html')
print(template.render(jiradb=jiradb))
```

`index.html` contents:

```
<table>
    {% for item in jiradb %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.key|rstrip("\n!") }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.summary|rstrip("\n!") }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Resolution|rstrip("\n!") }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Prints:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>CNSSDEBUG-151394</td>
        <td>[Lenovo][NFA344A][Win10] - [QCA6174_9377.WIN.1.0-10366-QCARMTFX86WZ-2] - Undetermined crash root cause</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>CNSSDEBUG-151395</td>
        <td>Some other summary</td>
        <td>fixed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Much better approach long term .. but this doesn't actually answer the general question of avoiding `None`

Comment: @kdopen yeah, you are right, let me provide a sample. Thanks.